# Android Import File Intent

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I'm using the class FileUtils and library  ipaulpro.afilechooser. 
I fixed my code but I get "copyFile" underlined in red. Will you help me understand why? Thanks

```
private void import(File from){

    File to = new File("/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/databases/cio.db"); 

    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(from, to);
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.Toast_o) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.Toast_to) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == this.FILE_CHOOSE){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            // The URI of the selected file 
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            // Create a File from this Uri
            File file = com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.utils.FileUtils.getFile(uri);
            importDB(file);
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Move your mouse over the part of the line underlined in red. What's the error message?

Comment: Please show your import statement

Comment: The error is Change to getFile

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no method called copyFile in https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java
FileUtils of  ipaulpro.afilechooser.

Answer (score 0):

The copyFile method is available in the `android.os.FileUtil` [class](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/android/os/FileUtils.html), but it looks like you are using `ipaulpro.afilechooser`.

If you want to use the `android.os` change your code to

```
android.os.FileUtils.copyFile(from, to);
```

Although personally I would find it a bit confusing and maybe unnecessary to use both versions of this class.